# as.Date yields NA for month name "März" (march)

Tags: xml, r, date

I got a scraped character vector with dates. My problem: When using `as.Date()`, every date containing the month name "März" (= which means "march" in German) is `NA` ed. Why is that?

Here is an (hopefully reproducible) example:

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(getURL("http://www.amazon.de/product-reviews/3836218984/?ie=UTF8&pageNumber=5&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=byRankDescending"), 
                 encoding="UTF-8")
(dates <- xpathSApply(doc, "//div/span[2]/nobr", xmlValue))
# [1] "12. Februar 2009"   "12. November 2006"  "19. März 2010"     
# [4] "30. Juni 2007"      "7. März 2006"       "19. März 2007"     
# [7] "22. Januar 2006"    "24. September 2005" "15. Februar 2012"  
# [10] "28. März 2007" 

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "German") # on Windows, see ?Sys.setlocale
as.Date(dates,  "%d. %B %Y")
# [1] "2009-02-12" "2006-11-12" NA           "2007-06-30" NA          
# [6] NA           "2006-01-22" "2005-09-24" "2012-02-15" NA
```

**Any ideas on what to try next?**

Note that if I apply the same on the `dput`ed and copy/pasted character vector, everything is fine:

```
dates <- c("12. Februar 2009", "12. November 2006", "19. März 2010", "30. Juni 2007", 
           "7. März 2006", "19. März 2007", "22. Januar 2006", "24. September 2005", 
           "15. Februar 2012", "28. März 2007")
as.Date(dates,  "%d. %B %Y")
# [1] "2009-02-12" "2006-11-12" "2010-03-19" "2007-06-30"
# [5] "2006-03-07" "2007-03-19" "2006-01-22" "2005-09-24"
# [9] "2012-02-15" "2007-03-28"
```

**For completeness my session info:**

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my mac. So, the problem is not related to the data.

Comment: The problem is related to not understanding what the settings of your machine are and the default encodings. That is the purpose of the Posing Guide for Rhalp asking that questioners post the results of `sessionInfo()`. (Not that anybody pays any attention to the request.)

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat Valid point. I thought the `Sys.setlocale` line gave enough info. For completeness, I added the session info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could reproduce this on Windows 7 x64. There are many issues with how R and Windows interact with character encoding, and I don't pretend to understand them. In your case, simply converting to `latin1` encoding before converting to a `Date` should work.

```
as.Date(iconv(dates,from='UTF-8',to='latin1'),'%d. %B %Y')
#  [1] "2009-02-12" "2006-11-12" "2010-03-19" "2007-06-30" "2006-03-07" "2007-03-19"
#  [7] "2006-01-22" "2005-09-24" "2012-02-15" "2007-03-28"
```

There might be a way to get `as.Date` to recognize different encodings in Windows, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 3):

I also had a quite similar issue. 
I'm going to write the solution I found hoping to help users with Italian local system setting

```
 Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME")
```

[1] "Italian_Italy.1252"

and I had to convert factors to date: factors were

```
levels(dates)
```

[1] "1. Jun. 2012"  "11. Sep. 2012" "19. Oct. 2012" "20. Mar. 2013" "28. Jun. 2012"
[6] "7. May. 2012"

This produced NA in the conversion for all months but March (because the abbreviation is the same in Italian)

```
 head(as.Date(dates, format= "%d. %b. %Y"))
```

[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

```
 summary(GEM_variability$date)

    Min.      1st Qu.       Median         Mean      3rd Qu.         Max.
```

"2013-03-20" "2013-03-20" "2013-03-20" "2013-03-20" "2013-03-20" "2013-03-20" 
        NA's 
       "559"

I found the solution in the help file of ?strftime

```
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
dates<- as.Date(date, format="%d. %b. %Y")
#dates<- strptime(date, format="%d. %b. %Y")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment/answer extension.

I had almost the same problem.

For example, with

```
months <- c("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", 
            "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC")
for (month in months) print(
     as.Date(iconv(paste("01", month, "2014", sep=""), 
                  from='UTF-8', to='latin1'), "%d%b%Y"))
```

I got

```
[1] "2014-01-01"
[1] "2014-02-01"
[1] NA
[1] "2014-04-01"
[1] NA
[1] "2014-06-01"
[1] "2014-07-01"
[1] "2014-08-01"
[1] "2014-09-01"
[1] NA
[1] "2014-11-01"
[1] "2014-12-01"
```

So I do not have dates for March, May and October (using `iconv()` or not was irrelevant with the specific arguments).

What solved it was:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")
```

Then I got everything correctly (`iconv()` wasn't necessary).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with German month names (abbreviated) on a Windows machine. Changing `Sys.setlocale()` did not help.

```
df = data.frame(date=c("01-Jan-2020","01-Feb-2020","01-Mär-2020","01-Apr-2020","01-Mai-2020","01-Jun-2020",
                       "01-Jul-2020","01-Aug-2020","01-Sep-2020","01-Okt-2020","01-Nov-2020","01-Dez-2020"))

as.Date(df$date, format="%d-%b-%Y")
```

Output:

```
[1] "2020-01-01" "2020-02-01" NA           "2020-04-01" "2020-05-01" "2020-06-01"
[7] "2020-07-01" "2020-08-01" "2020-09-01" "2020-10-01" "2020-11-01" "2020-12-01"
```

The standard `as.Date()` function fails to recognize `Mär`. Even when I simply replace `ä` to `a` (essentially English month abbreviations), the same error occurs when using `as.Date()`.

**My solution:**

Replacing `ä` to `a` and using [`lubridate`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) worked.

```
df$date = gsub("ä","a",df$date)

library(lubridate)
dmy(df$date)
```

Output:

```
 [1] "2020-01-01" "2020-02-01" "2020-03-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-05-01" "2020-06-01"
 [7] "2020-07-01" "2020-08-01" "2020-09-01" "2020-10-01" "2020-11-01" "2020-12-01"
```